# how can i insert data to database using json php mysqli?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

My problem is that I get a response with everything null..
On my subscirbers file I have a class with a function and a query that selects all users.

On my comments file I have a class with a function and  a query that inserts the comment

```
  if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task']=='comment_insert'){    
    $userId = (int)$_POST ['userId'];
    $comment = addslashes($_POST ['comment']);

    $std = new stdClass();
    $std->user= null;
    $std->userId= null;
    $std->comment= null;
    $std->error=false ; 

    require_once( "subscribers.php" );
    require_once( "comments.php" );
    require_once( "db_conx.php" );
    if ( class_exists( 'Comments ' ) && class_exists( 'Subscribers'))

    {   
        $userInfo = Subscribers::getSubscriber($userId);

        if($userId == null)
        {
            $std-> error = true ;
        }


        $commentInfo = Comments::insert($comment, $userId);

        if($commentsInfo != null )
        {
            $std->error = true ;
        }


        $std->user = $userInfo;
        $std->comment = $commentInfo;



    }   
        echo json_encode($std); 



}

else

{
    die;
}

?>
```

Comment: you have a typo here $std-> error = true ; not that it has anything to  do with your problem, just a heads up.

Answer (score -1):

just convert your object to array

```
$array =  (array) $std;
echo json_encode($array);
```